# Joining on closest date [Amazon Redshift]

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

I am trying to do a left join on Event_1 and Event_2 over the same user ID and to the greatest previous date.

Event_1

```
| timestamp               | user_id | n_trigg |
|-------------------------|---------|---------|
| 2021-04-24 15:39:51.667 | 1213    | 1       |
| 2021-04-24 15:40:13.631 | 1213    | 2       |
| 2021-04-24 18:51:22.651 | 1213    | 3       |
```

Event_2 (happens after Event_1)

```
| timestamp             | user_id | product_id |
|-----------------------|---------|------------|
|2021-04-24 15:39:56.483| 1213    | 11313      |
|2021-04-24 15:40:14.775| 1213    | 11313      |
```

I want to have the following result:

| timestamp_event_1 | user_id | n_trigg | timestamp_event_2 | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-24 15:39:51.667 | 1213 | 1 | 2021-04-24 15:39:56.483 | 11313 |
| 2021-04-24 15:40:13.631 | 1213 | 2 | 2021-04-24 15:40:14.775 | 11313 |

I have tried this, but it's not working on Redshift:

```
SELECT *
FROM Event_1 LEFT JOIN Event_2 ON Event_1.user_id = Event_2.user_id 
      AND Event_2.timestamp = (select min(timestamp) from Event_2 
                                        where Event_2.user_id=Event_1.user_id 
                                        and Event_2.timestamp > Event_1.timestamp)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet
```

Thank you very much in advance.
Using Redshift 1.0.29551

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who may encounter the same problem, this is the answer that was provided to me by a colleague:

```
select
    "timestamp",
    user_id,
    n_trigg,
    timestamp_event_2,
    product_id
from
    (--a
    select
        e1."timestamp",
        e1.user_id,
        e1.n_trigg,
        e2."timestamp" timestamp_event_2,
        e2.product_id,
        row_number() over (partition by e1.n_trigg order by e2."timestamp" asc) ranking
    from
        event_1 e1
    join
        event_2 e2 on e1.user_id = e2.user_id and e2."timestamp" > e1."timestamp"
    ) a
where
    ranking = 1
```

Comment: This is an interesting question and when I had time I explored it further.  I've written a blog post on it with code and analysis - http://wad-design.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sql_limits_wp_2.html  So if you are working with very large tables or are seeing speeds that aren't what you like then take a look.  There is a faster way to perform a closest date join when data gets large.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says Redshift doesn't support this type of correlated subquery.  So you need to rewrite it to be a JOIN instead.  If these tables are large just be careful doing inequality joins as this can lead to data explosions.  If this happens there are some UNION and window techniques that can get you past this issue.